# glArrayElement error

Tags: opengl

Can someone explain to me this error, please:
GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it fires when you have a VBO actively bound via a pointer function (e.g. `glVertexAttribPointer`) at the same time the VBO is mapped to client memory with `glMapBuffer`.

You can't use a VBO while it's mapped to client memory, according to the `glMapBuffer` doc:

> A mapped data store must be unmapped with glUnmapBuffer before its buffer object is used.
>               Otherwise an error will be generated by any GL command that attempts to dereference the buffer object's data store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
can you think about example of this error in opengl 1.4?  
Because i'm trying to understand if this error can appear specifically in openGL 1.4. And your example is from opengl 1.5 and above.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know. If you're getting this error in your own code, maybe you should post the code snippet that is generating it. @user893269

Comment: @user893269: It doesn't matter; you cannot use a buffer object that is currently mapped. ARB_map_buffer_range allows you to only map part of a buffer (thus allowing the rest to be used). But without that, if the buffer is mapped, you can't use it. Whether it's `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer`, etc; it cannot be rendered from.